# TCPDF, making custom font text bold without separate ttf file

Tags: tcpdf

My project involves me creating a pdf with imputed text (with a custom font) that looks something like this:

```
@font-face{font-family:font1;src:url('fonts/font1.ttf');}
<p><span style="font-family: 'font1'; font-size: 12px;"><This is<strong>test</strong> text</span></span></p>
```

It uses the custom font perfectly except that bold and italic text look normal. The text is formatted bold when you copy/paste it out of the pdf it's just not showing in the pdf. I know I can incorporate a separate bold ttf file for my custom font, but I'd like to know if I can get around that. If I open the text above as an html, it is properly displayed so I know it must be possible